Create a composition function that inherits the types of its extensions
I am trying to create a function that accepts extensions as arguments, and returns an object that is typed as the combination of all the extensions.
To better illustrate, here is a basic example:
const withNotification = () => ({ notify: (message: string): void => void 0 });
const withDialog = () => ({ dialog: (data: any): void => void 0 });

const compose = (...extensions: any[]): any => null!;

const composed = compose(withNotification(), withDialog());

// When writing the following, the signature should be recognized
composed.notify('OK'); // Works
composed.notify(0);    // Does not work (not a string)
composed.dialog({});  // Works
composed.dialog();    // Does not work (no parameter)

My approach so far is the following:
type Extension<T extends object> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] };

const withNotification = () => ({ notify: (message: string): void => void 0 });
const withDialog = () => ({ dialog: (data: any): void => void 0 });

const compose = <T extends object>(...extensions: Extension<T>[]): T => null!;

const composed = compose(withNotification(), withDialog());

composed.notify('OK');
composed.notify(0);
composed.dialog({});
composed.dialog();

What happens is that calling notify is recognized, whereas dialog is not. I understand that this is because my T generic that is not "spreading" to all extensions, but I don't know how to achieve that.
StackBlitz

• Don't use Object, use object instead; please [edit]. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz this seems to do exactly what I have asked, thank you ! I would absolutely love an explanation on that, thank you for offering :)

Presumably you want the return type of compose() to look like what would happen if it's implemented as a spread (such as using Object.assign()).  TypeScript doesn't have a native "spread" type operator, although this is requested at microsoft/TypeScript#10727.
But if we can assume that the arguments' properties have no overlap, then we can model compose() as returning the intersection of the types of its arguments.  So if you call compose(a, b, c) where a is of type A, b is of type B, and c is of type C, then you want the return type to be A & B & C.  (If there is overlap then the intersection will combine the properties instead of using the last one.)
That means we should write compose() to be generic in the type T of the extensions rest parameter (which will be a tuple type in practice, like [A, B, C] for the above example), and return a value of type TupleToIntersection<T> for an appropriately defined TupleToIntersection<T>:
const compose = <T extends object[]>(...extensions: T): TupleToIntersection<T> =>
    Object.assign({}, ...extensions); // might as well implement it

Here's one way to write TupleToIntersection<T>:
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void } extends
    Record<`${number}`, (x: infer U) => void> ? U : never;

This takes advantage of the fact that if you infer a single type parameter from multiple types in a contravariant position (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) then it infers an intersection.  This is similar to the approach mentioned in Transform union type to intersection type.  It maps the tuple to another tuple where the types are in the contravariant position (a function parameter), and then matches it against a Record type where the keys are numeric and the property is a single function parameter.  Using the example above, we map [A, B, C] to [(x: A)=>void, (x: B)=>void, (x: C)=>void] and then match against Record<`${number}`, (x: A & B & C)=>void>.
Let's test it out:
const withNotification = () => ({ notify: (message: string): void => void 0 });
const withDialog = () => ({ dialog: (data: any): void => void 0 });      

const composed = compose(withNotification(), withDialog());
// const composed: { notify: (message: string) => void; } & 
//                 { dialog: (data: any) => void; }

composed.notify('OK'); // okay
composed.notify(0); // error
composed.dialog({}); // okay
composed.dialog(); // error

Looks good. The type of composed is the intersection of the types of withNotification() and withDialog(), and so it is known to have both a notify method and a dialog method.
Playground link to code
